# HTTPS RewriteCond with two / routes

Tags: mod-rewrite, https

i have n URL like this:

```
http://name.co/othername/xname 
http://name.co/othername/yname
```

So name.co/othername are equal. Just the 'xname' is changing to a different.

I need a redirect to the HTTPS Side.

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but the result was not correct. it would be nice if someone could help me

Answer (score 1):

`REQUEST_URI` will exclude the query string. Also, you need flags, at least [R] and usually [L] as well. You will probably want a 301 redirect in this case, unless you think you are likely to turn this off later. Try replacing the `RewriteRule` you have with:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The R flag means to actually send a redirect to the browser as opposed to just changing how the URL is handled insternally; the L flag means this is the last directive that should be processed; it shortcuts the rest of the processing and avoids any additional changes made by other rules.